# Implementing JSON Web Encryption in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, jwe

I'm looking for a way to use [JSON Web Encryption (JWE)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption-16) in a Node.js service. I have however only managed to find implementations of the related standard [JWS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jws). There are however several libraries for other languages, such as [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWE%20Examples).

Did anyone successfully implement JWE in Javascript? I'm afraid I'm gonna gave to resort to implementing the spec myself using lower level primitives. Is there a better approach?

Comment: were you able to find a good JWE library? I'm now in the same boat and having trouble finding one that supports A256GCMKW

Comment: Woah it's been a while. :-) I honestly can't remember what I ended up doing, but maybe you should look into Blacksonic's answer below?. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a library that can be used from Node.js also https://github.com/cisco/node-jose.
They have also a very good documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library **js-jose** https://github.com/square/js-jose.
But it works only for Chrome. It does not work for Internet Explorer nor for FireFox.

Comment: Thanks! It appears this library is currently explicitly limited to client side usage and the author mentions some efforts needed to run this with Node.js. Anyway it might be worth looking at. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using Node's `crypto` library, below uses a 256 bit (GCM) AES Key in a direct encryption scheme.

```
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer';
import fs from "node:fs";
import url from 'node:url';
import path from "node:path";
const {createCipheriv, createDecipheriv, createSecretKey, randomFill, generateKey} = await import('node:crypto');
var aesKey;
var claims = {name:"Joe",roles:["member","admin"]};

(async function () {
  console.log("\x1b[31mInvalid Token")
  aesKey = await generateSecretKey();
  let jwe = await returnJWE(claims);
  console.log("\x1b[37mYour JWE token is: " + consoleString(jwe));
  console.log("Paste JSON Web Token In Terminal Then Press Enter.")
})();

async function decryptJWE(jwe) {
  try {
    let parts = jwe.split(".");
    let encodedJWEProtectedHeader = parts[0];
    let protectedHeaderBuffer = Buffer.from(encodedJWEProtectedHeader,'base64url');
    let cipherText = parts[3];
    let tag = parts[4];
    let tagBuffer = Buffer.from(tag,'base64url');
    let iv = Buffer.from(parts[2],'base64url');
    const decipher = createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', aesKey, iv);
    decipher.setAAD(protectedHeaderBuffer);
    decipher.setAuthTag(tagBuffer);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(cipherText,'base64url','utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    return JSON.parse(decrypted);
  } catch (e) {
    return "\x1b[31mInvalid Token!\x1b[37m";
  }
}

function generateInitializationVector () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let buf = Buffer.alloc(32); //makes 256 bit
    randomFill(buf, (err, buf) => {
      if (err) reject (err);
      resolve(buf);
    });
  });
}

function generateSecretKey () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    generateKey('aes', { length: 256 }, (err, key) => {
      if (err) {
        reject (err);
      }
      resolve (key)
    });
  });
}

async function returnJWE(claimsObject){
  let headerObject = {"alg":"dir","enc":"A256GCM"}; 
  let headerString = JSON.stringify(headerObject);
  let iv = await generateInitializationVector();
  let claimsString = JSON.stringify(claimsObject);
  let claimsBase64URLEncoded = Buffer.from(claimsString).toString('base64url');
  let cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', aesKey, iv);
  cipher.setAAD(Buffer.from(headerString));
  cipher.setAutoPadding();
  let encrypted = cipher.update(claimsString,'utf8','base64url');
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64url');
  let tag = cipher.getAuthTag().toString('base64url');
  let encryptedKey = "";
  let ivString = Buffer.from(iv).toString('base64url');
  let encodedJWEProtectedHeader = Buffer.from(headerString).toString('base64url');
  let result = encodedJWEProtectedHeader + "." + encryptedKey + "." + ivString + "." + encrypted + "." + tag;
  return result;
}

export default {decryptJWE, returnJWE};

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('readable', async () => {
  let chunk;
  while ((chunk = process.stdin.read()) !== null) {
    console.log(await decryptJWE(chunk));
  }
});

function consoleString(token){
  let tokenParts = token.split(/(\.)/);
  let colors = ["32m","31m","33m","34m","36m"];
  let color = "\x1b[X";
  let str = ""
  //str += color
  tokenParts.forEach(function(part,index){
    if(part != "."){
      str += color.replace("X",colors.shift())
    }
    str += part;
    str += "\x1b[37m"
  })
  return str;
}
```